# Potential Makefile bug with Target-specific Variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I recently discovered that
setting a Target-specific Variable
using a conditional assignment (`?=`)
has the effect of unexporting the global variable using the same name.

For example:
`target: CFLAGS ?= -O2`

If this statement is anywhere in the Makefile, it has the same impact as `unexport CFLAGS` for the global variable.

It means that the `CFLAGS` passed as environment variable to the `Makefile` will not be passed as environment variable to any sub-makefile, as if it was never set.

Could it be a `make` bug ?
I couldn't find any mention of this side effect in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).

Example : root `Makefile`

```
target:
    $(MAKE) -C $(DIR) target

disruptor: CFLAGS ?= -O1
disruptor: 
    @echo CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
```

and then into `$DIR/Makefile`:

```
target:
    @echo target CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
```

Now :

- `make` will display `target CFLAGS =`
- `make CFLAGS=-Os` will display `target CFLAGS = -Os`
- but `CFLAGS=-Os make` will display `target CFLAGS =`
- after commenting the first `disruptor` line (`CFLAGS ?= -O1`), then `CFLAGS=-Os make` will display `target CFLAGS = -Os` as expected.

Other mitigations that work :

- adding `export CFLAGS` *after* the first `disruptor` line
- replacing the `?=` assignment by `=`, `:=` or `+=`. None of them produce the "implicit unexport" side effect (of course, it also changes the assignment meaning, this is just for test).

I haven't tested with other variable names yet, but I presume it's not specific to `CFLAGS`.

Comment: The effect you describe does sound surprising, but I would want to see a complete example before opining about the observed behavior.

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce your observed behavior with GNU `make` 4.0.  I concur with your characterization that the effect seems to be as if the variable in question had been `unexport`ed, and I confirm that the same effect is observed with other variable names, including names that are without any special significance to `make`.

This effect is undocumented as far as I can tell, and unexpected.  It seems to conflict with [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific), in that the manual describes target-specific variable values as causing a separate instance of the affected variable to be created, so as to avoid affecting the global one, yet we do see the global one being affected.

> Could it be a `make` bug ?

It indeed does look like a bug to me.  Evidently to other people, too, as it appears that [the issue has already been reported](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=59230).